# Tangent line to a function at c that passes through the origin

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we are given a function $f$, which is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and there exists the line $y = bx$ where $b$ is a finite value, that crosses $f(x)$ in at least two points in $(0,1)$.

I want to prove that there is a $c \in (0, 1)$ such that the tangent line to $f(c)$ passes through the origin.

Since the line, $y = mx$, crosses $f(x)$ at least two points in $(0, 1)$ the function has to move similar to a sine function on $x \in (0, 1)$ Now if I use the MVT I can find a point $c$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $f'(c) = m$, but this is not of interest since it is clear that the tangent at $c$ would not pass through the origin.

Now from this we can see that if the line crosses $f(x)$ at every point in $(0,1)$ the line is the function $f(x)$ on $(0, 1)$ and for any $x \in (0, 1)$ the tangent at $x$ would pass through the origin.

But now I am stuck in the process where we have to find such $c$ where the line crosses $f(x)$ in at least two points in $(0, 1)$.

Can you give some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1< x_2$ be two points in $(0,1)$ such that $f(x_i) = bx_i$. On the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ the function $g(x) = f(x)/x$ is differentiable. Furthermore we have $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$. Applying Rolle's theorem we know that there exists a $c \in [x_1,x_2]$ such that $g'(c) = 0$. This means that $f'(c)c - f(c) = 0$. Now it's a simple formality to see that the tangent at the point $(c,f(c))$ at the graph of $f$ passes through the origin.

How did I get to this solution? The fact that $f$ intersects $y=bx$ into two points gives the first clue. If we imagine that the line $y=bx$ rotates upwards while still passing through the origin, we can see that there should be a point where it is tangent to the graph of $f$. This point corresponds to the point where $f(x)/x$ is maximal. We cannot reason on $(0,1)$ since we can be close to division by zero when $x$ is small. Reducing the problem to $[x_1,x_2]$ solves this problem, and we immediately see that on this interval we can apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: $g(x)$ is just $b$ in your proof.

Comment: Also this shows only for a function in the form $f(x) /x$, not every differentiable function.

Comment: $g(x)$ is not constant $b$. It has values $b$ just in the points $x_1,x_2$ and in between it may take other values. I don't understand your second comment. The answer works for every differentiable function $f$.

Comment: I am misunderstanding your proof. What does $g(x) = f(x) / x$ represent in your proof? Where does this come from?

Comment: It is a function that we can define starting from $f$.